# Can I identify the type of encryption from a password, public key and my encrypted password?

Tags: encryption, hash, public-key-encryption

I have a password: `myCoolPassword`

I have an encrypted password, for example `324lrwefglkn2tlk24htlk2hglkn42jbt32lk3tb23lkb`

I also have access to the encryption key `myCoolKey`

Is there any way of me working out what **type** of encryption/hashing my server is using from these three things? With the system I am using it is unclear what type of encryption is being used.

Comment: Your encryption key does not look like a proper key for a block cipher which usually have specific lengths. Your "ciphertext" does not look like a it's a known encoding of a modern cipher or hashing algorithm. Perhaps your example is self made. Anyway, the answer is *no* with a high probability. (note that public-key encryption is not used at all in the realm of password encryption, you have to look into the definition of it)

Comment: @Artjom these are not my real password and keys ;)

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what type of encryption it is, if it has been [salted](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salt_(cryptography)) etc... one way to find out given those information is to loop through the well known encryption algorithms and encrypt your password with the key and see if it matches with the encrypted password but Of course this might not always work

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I was hoping not to have to loop through hundreds of encryption algorithms! :P

Comment: @BarneyChambers Then the answer is no, you can't tell.